# Unable to start AMS Acomba Connector on Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

I am trying to get a python service to run under Windows 7 however I am unable to start it.

I have started by installing the service using

```
c:\amsconnector>amsconnector.py --username domain\admin --password ************ install
Installing service AMS Acomba Connector
Service installed
```

After that, I run

```
c:\amsconnector>amsconnector.py start
Starting service AMS Acomba Connector
```

When I check the running services list, I notice that the service is not running and when checking the event log, I am presented with this stacktrace

```
Python could not import the service's module 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\amsconnector\amsconnector.py", line 343, in <module>
win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(AMSConnectorService)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\win32serviceutil.py", line 521, in HandleCommandLine
usage()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\win32serviceutil.py", line 505, in usage
sys.exit(1)
SystemExit: 1 
%2: %3
```

The line 343 of amsconnector.py looks like this

```
if True or __name__ == '__main__':
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(AMSConnectorService)
```

After checking out the source code of win32serviceutil.py, it appears that the service is just printing out the win32service usage dialog instead of actually running the python class. I am completely confused!

Comment: Usually it's the mistake of wrong args. Have you check that?

Comment: `if True or __name__ == '__main__':` I think you should remove the `True` from that test, that looks like some quick test code during development.

Comment: @michael_stackof It is indeed an argument problem because according to the win32serviceutil source it is just printing out the usage even though that should not happen because I have already installed the service.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks roeland!

I was able to fix the issue by simply removing the "True or" part of the last line leaving it like this:

```
if True or __name__ == '__main__':
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(AMSConnectorService)
```